# InstallShield 2011 Immediate execution in System Context

Tags: windows, windows-installer, windows-server-2008-r2, installshield-2011

I want to write a custom action which will execute above all other custom actions and execute in system context. If I use "immediate execution" then it executes in logged in users context and if I use "deferred execution in system context" then this custom action executes after other custom actions. What should I do to handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only *deferred* actions can be executed in system context. It is executed at its scheduled sequence between other deferred actions. If this action must be the first action run, you would need a bootstrapper which will elevate permissions and the start your installation.

Note also: Deferred actions have very limited access to the properties of the install.